# Print multiple variables with one command in jdb

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

How can I print multiple local primitives with one command in jdb (verison 1.4)?

I've tried:

```
print v1, v2, v3
```

but that only prints out the value of v1.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:** Effectively I need a watch in jdb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the following do what you want?

```
print "" + v1 + " " + v2 + " " + v3
```

Comment: This works technically, but it's still cumbersome (the line is long).  Is there a way to assign this to a macro or the like?

Comment: I don't know of any macro like facility, although you could try running it under rlwrap (http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/) so that you can at least use command history to print out the same values again.